# (WinDbg) How can I switch back to the kernel context after I've switched into a process context with WinDbg (kernel-mode)?

Tags: command, kernel, windbg, ntdll, reversing

Is there a way to switch back to the original context after I've switched to a process context with WinDbg?
I've used these commands:

To get the process address:

```
!process 0 0 myprocess.exe
```

and then to switch to myprocess.exe context this command:

```
.process /i /r /p <address>
```

now how can I switch back to physical addresses?
I would like to debug a function starting from a syscall in myprocess.exe into the ntdll function following the whole path with WinDbg, but once I'm in the process context I don't know how to get back to physical addresses in order to keep debugging ntdll after the syscall is done.

I've already tried to search online I couldn't find an answer, thanks.

Comment: syscall is the last um call and it is already in ntdll youcanchange process context using the same commands youquote list allprocess contexts with !process 0 0 and change to any process context using .process /r /p _EPROCESS

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I would like to follow ntdll in the system tho not usermode, so I would like to switch the context back to the kernel, I don't want to stay in a usermode process context, how can I do that?

Comment: i am still at loss [see if this answer is of anyuse to you](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25515/how-could-i-follow-a-system-call-from-a-dll-kernel-driver-syscall/25519#25519)

Comment: That is indeed helpful although it doesn't answer to my question (I'm asking if that's possible).
Anyway still a valid way to do that, so wish I could give you reputation or something back ,thank you

Comment: you could upvote that answer if you prefer to anyway i answered your query below

Answer (score 1):

Assuming You Have a Proper Kernel Debugging Environment Setup You can Trace From user Mode into KernelMode and Back To User Mode

As An Example shown Below is a Stripped Lowlevel CreateFile Call
It Starts from the last leg of Journey in usermode at ntdll.dll
compile link and transfer the executable to the target machine
and use either ntsd -d exe from target
or use !gflag +ksl; sxe ld:ntcfile in host windbg
sxe ld: is once per boot
for ntsd -d you need windbg installed in target
Read Documentation about both ways first
you can also look at [some of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3622813%20ntsd)

```
//poc and Demo code using fragile semi-documented functions and magic constants
//compiled and linked in vs2017 community in x86 as x86 with cmd dev prompt 
// will produce a barebone ~1kb exe on successful execution will create or  
//open a zero byte text file testfile.txt in c:\ 
#include <windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib ,"ntdll.lib")
UNICODE_STRING      FileName    = { 38,40, L"\\??\\C:\\testfile.txt"    }; 
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   Ob          = { 0x18,NULL,&FileName,0x40,NULL,NULL  }; 
IO_STATUS_BLOCK     ioStatus; 
HANDLE              Out;
int main(void) { 
    NtCreateFile(&Out,0x80000000,&Ob,&ioStatus,NULL,0x80,0,3,0,NULL,0);
    return (int)Out;
}
```

compiled linked executed and verified

```
:\>ls -lg c:\testfile.txt
ls: c:\testfile.txt: No such file or directory

:\>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /nologo ntcfile.cpp /link /release /entry:main /subsystem:windows /fixed
ntcfile.cpp

:\>powershell -c "(Start-Process -PassThru -Wait .\ntcfile.exe).ExitCode"
12

:\>ls -lg c:\testfile.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0 0 2021-01-04 01:21 c:\testfile.txt
```

shown below is a walk through using the code above in a host and target

```
$$ on executing ntsd -d in target you get a user mode prompt in kernel debugger 
$$ issue .breakin to change mode 
.breakin
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction:
82882d00 cc              int     3
```

look for EPROCESS of interest

```
kd> !process 0 0 ntcfile.exe
PROCESS 84386828  SessionId: 1  Cid: 04d8    Peb: 7ffdf000  ParentCid: 01a4
    DirBase: 0b1eb000  ObjectTable: 96f2a970  HandleCount:   4.
    Image: ntcfile.exe
```

Set Process Specific Breakpoint on kernel mode ddi wrt user mode api
( mostly same named function in ntdll) and continue (f5 or g->enter)
you will return back to user mode prompt debug as you normally debug
an user mode executable if youstep into a sysenter for which have set
a kernel modebreakpoint your will break in kernel mode in proper
process context

```
kd> bp /p 84386828 nt!NtCreateFile
kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  82a7642e     0001 (0001) nt!NtCreateFile
     Match process data 84386828

kd> g
0:000> g @$exentry
g @$exentry

eax=77533c33 ebx=7ffdf000 ecx=00000000 edx=00401000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=00401000 esp=0012ff8c ebp=0012ff94 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntcfile!main:
00401000 55              push    ebp
```

reload symbols in user mode it will load the transferred pdb in target ntsd

```
0:000> .reload /f ntcfile.exe=0x400000,4000
.reload /f ntcfile.exe=0x400000,4000
0:000> lmm ntc*
lmm ntc*
start    end        module name
00400000 00404000   ntcfile    (private pdb symbols)  c:\Users\winsev\Desktop\ntcfile.pdb

0:000> $$ this pdb is in target transferred along with binary for ntsd -d to work
$$ this pdb is in target transferred along with binary for ntsd -d to work
```

disassembly of the main

```
0:000> uf .
uf .
ntcfile!main:
00401000 55              push    ebp
00401001 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00401003 6a00            push    0
00401005 6a00            push    0
00401007 6a00            push    0
00401009 6a03            push    3
0040100b 6a00            push    0
0040100d 6880000000      push    80h
00401012 6a00            push    0
00401014 6820304000      push    offset ntcfile!ioStatus (00403020)
00401019 6808304000      push    offset ntcfile!Ob (00403008)
0040101e 6800000080      push    80000000h
00401023 6828304000      push    offset ntcfile!Out (00403028)
00401028 e807000000      call    ntcfile!NtCreateFile (00401034)
0040102d a128304000      mov     eax,dword ptr [ntcfile!Out (00403028)]
00401032 5d              pop     ebp
00401033 c3              ret
```

stepping through until sysenter for ntdll!NtCreateFile to break in nt!NtCreateFile

```
0:000> pc
ntcfile!main+0x28:
00401028 e807000000      call    ntcfile!NtCreateFile (00401034)
0:000> t
ntcfile!NtCreateFile:
00401034 ff2500204000    jmp     dword ptr [ntcfile!_imp__NtCreateFile (00402000)] ds:0023:00402000={ntdll!NtCreateFile (773e55c8)}
0:000> t
ntdll!NtCreateFile:
773e55c8 b842000000      mov     eax,42h
0:000> t
ntdll!NtCreateFile+0x5:
773e55cd ba0003fe7f      mov     edx,offset SharedUserData!SystemCallStub (7ffe0300)
0:000> t
ntdll!NtCreateFile+0xa:
773e55d2 ff12            call    dword ptr [edx]      ds:0023:7ffe0300={ntdll!KiFastSystemCall (773e70b0)}
0:000> t
ntdll!KiFastSystemCall:
773e70b0 8bd4            mov     edx,esp
0:000> t
773e70b2 0f34            sysenter
0:000> t
```

your are in kernel mode now

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
nt!NtCreateFile:
82a7642e 8bff            mov     edi,edi
kd> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 961bbd00 8285f87a 00403028 80000000 00403008 nt!NtCreateFile
01 961bbd00 773e70b4 00403028 80000000 00403008 nt!KiFastCallEntry+0x12a
02 0012ff50 773e55d4 0040102d 00403028 80000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
03 0012ff54 0040102d 00403028 80000000 00403008 ntdll!NtCreateFile+0xc
04 0012ff88 77533c45 7ffdf000 0012ffd4 774037f5 ntcfile!main+0x2d [c:\users\hp\desktop\ntcfile\ntcfile.cpp @ 14] 
05 0012ff94 774037f5 7ffdf000 775c0f6b 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
06 0012ffd4 774037c8 00401000 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
07 0012ffec 00000000 00401000 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


kd> $$ stack consists of both user mode and kernle mode components
```

Comment: thank you, I've upvoted you because you are indeed helpful but I want to try to elaborate more my question because I may have been too vague.

Comment: After I've got the EPROCESS as you did show me, I switch to its usermode context with this command:
process /i /r /p EPROCESS
then I press g in order to get into that process context, then I debug until the syscall is reached, but once I step into that call the debugger breaks into the kernel but it doesn't read the addresses.
in the disassembly It reads "??" everywhere I guess it's because the debugger it's still in the usermode context how can switch back to kernel in order to see the real values instead of ??